# Composer with local SVN repo

Tags: php, svn, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to run composer using a local SVN repo, I can hit the repo I want but composer keeps adding the `/branch` to the end of the URL.

How can I override this?

Here are the docs:

- http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

Example of what I have

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://host.com/externals/project",
        "trunk-path": "trunk",
        "branches-path": "branches",
        "tags-path": "tags",
        "reference": "symfony/symfony"
    }
],
"require": {
    "project/project": "svn-project"
}
```

Output is something like this:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                      
Repository http://host.com/externals/project/version could not be processed, 
svn: URL 'http://host.com/externals/project/version/branches' 
non-existent in that revision
```

Here is my subversion layout:

```
http://host.com/externals/project/version
```

- Externals are libraries like Symfony
- Project is Symfony
- version is 2.1.2

So my svn repo is like:

```
http://host.com/externals/symfony/2.1.2
```

any thoughts?

this is how the company I work for stores external libraries we are using

UPDATE:

I've changed our repo to this:

```
http://host.com/externals/symfony/trunk/ <-- empty directory
http://host.com/externals/symfony/branches/ <-- empty directory
http://host.com/externals/symfony/trunk/2.1.2 <-- holds the Symfony 2.1.2 release code
```

Now I get this message:

```
Reading composer.json of http://host.com/externals/symfony/ (2.1.2)
Importing tag 2.1.2 (2.1.2.0)
```

but it then still pulls from the github repo instead of my svn repo.

I've also read on Satis

- http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

but if I do there where do I host this?

- Which the project?
- On my SVN Repo?
- Elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Composer assumes you stick to the common repository layout of `/trunk`, `/branches`,  and `/tags`. Plus you must enter the URL to the repository root--not the full project path. You specify the project-specific path with `package-path`.

See the doc [Composer | Subversion Options](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#subversion-options).

> Since Subversion has no native concept of branches and tags, Composer
>   assumes by default that code is located in `$url/trunk`, `$url/branches`
>   and `$url/tags`. If your repository has a different layout you can
>   change those values.

Comment: That is correct, you should enter the root of the repository, composer will then scan it all and create versions for every branch/tag that contains a composer.json file. You can use `composer show package/name --verbose` to see which versions are detected and why (not).

Comment: @PhillPafford I don't know *why* you are trying to mirror stuff in your svn repo, but assuming you have a good reason what you probably want to do is disable packagist by adding `{"packagist": false}` in the repositories. Because at the moment I assume you require symfony/symfony without specific version and so it tries to install the latest which is coming from packagist and is cloned from github.

Comment: Thanks, this help me as well: http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md